# Logback config, puppet and application versions

Tags: logback, puppet

I am busy testing a new approach to managing a java application that uses logback on a puppet-managed host, and was wondering if anyone had some advice on the best approach for this. I am stuck with a catch 22 situation.

The java application is deployed to a host by an automated system (CI). The deployment writes an application version number to a file (e.g. /etc/app.version may contain "0001")

The logback config file (logback.xml) is managed by puppet.

I am trying to configure the application to include it's version number in the logging layout (e.g. `<pattern>VERSION: %version%</pattern>` . However, I am not sure on the approach, as there isn't an "include" function for the logback config file (to include a file with the version number into the logback config). At the same time, I don't see a way to get puppet to do a client-side template build, using the host-side file (I've tried using a template approach, but the template is compiled on the puppet server side).

Any idea's on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a [custom fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html). Facts are executed on the client.

Eg:

logback/manifests/init.pp

```
file { '/etc/logback.xml':
  content => template('logback/logback.xml.erb')
}
```

logback/templates/logback.xml.erb

```
...
<pattern>VERSION: <%= scope.lookupvar('::my_app_version') %></pattern>
...
```

logback/lib/facter/my_app_version.rb

```
Facter.add('my_app_version') do
  setcode do
    begin
       File.read('/etc/app.version')
    rescue
       nil
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps. I think in Puppet < 3.0 you will have to set "pluginsync = true" in puppet.conf to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, Facts will suit my needs perfectly.